# Show by counting two ways that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(n-i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i\choose 2}={n+1 \choose 3}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> [image: >]

I am trying to understand what he is counting in two ways in the first and second equality. I noticed that ${i \choose 2}=\frac{i(i-1)}{2}$ is the sum of the first $(i-1)$ integers. I did the following:

- I expanded both sums and showed that they are equal.
- I wrote ${n+1 \choose 3}=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{6}$ and showed it is equal to one of the sums.

---

But judging from the section where the author writes about counting in two ways, it seems something else should be done:

> [image]

> [image]

I struggled a lot to find a figure such as the one he found in this example. Although I understood that ${i \choose 2}=\frac{i(i-1)}{2}$ and hence that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {i \choose 2}$ is the sum of the sums of the first $i$ integers, I couldn't match the first sum to it in any meaningful way, I also don't know how to match the sums to ${n+1 \choose 3}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Reading across gives the second series. Reading down gives the first.

In maths,

$$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_\limits{j=1}^i j = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_\limits{j=1}^{n-i} i$$
Replacing the $i$ and $j$ variables with $\sum_\limits{k=1}^j 1$ and $\sum_\limits{k=1}^i 1$ respectively gives three summations over $1$ with equal ranges.

Second to third is the [Hockey Stick Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

If we say the $n^{th}$ integer is the sum of $n\;1$'s, then the sum of $n$ integers is the sum of the sum of $n\;1$'s, and then the sum of $n$ sum of integers is the sum of the sum of the sum of $n\;1$'s.

$$\binom{n}{1}=\sum_\limits{i=1}^n 1$$
$$\binom{n}{2}=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_\limits{j=1}^i 1$$
$$\binom{n}{3}=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-2} \sum_\limits{j=1}^i \sum_\limits{k=1}^j 1$$

And in pictures:

```
1
1 1         1
1 1 1       1 1       1
1 1 1 1     1 1 1     1 1     1
1 1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1   1 1 1   1 1   1
```

Comment: I like this solution the best because I think it is the most accessible, most visual, most straightforward.

Answer (score 10):

Consider choosing $3$ distinct numbers from $n+1$ numbers. Obviously there are $\binom{n+1}{3}$ way to do this.

Another way to count this: first choose $(i+1)$ as the second biggest number, then choose the smallest number from $(1,...,i)$ and choose the biggest number from $(i+2,...,n+1)$. $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{\ i(n-i)}$

Yet another way to count this: first choose $(i+1)$ as the biggest number, then choose the two smaller numbers from $(1,...,i)$. $\sum_{i=2}^{n}{\binom{i}{2}}$

Bonus: first choose $i+1$ as the smallest number, then choose the two bigger numbers from $(i+2,...,n+1)$. $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}{\binom{n-i\ \ }{2}}$

$$
\binom{n+1}{3}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{i(n-i)}=\sum_{i=2}^{n}{\binom{i}{2}}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}{\binom{n-i}{2}}
$$

Answer (score 4):

I would add a third way: you may notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(n-k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k(n-k)$ is a convolution, namely
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k(n-k) = [x^n]\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}k x^k\right)^2.\tag{1}$$
Stars&bars can be written in the following way:
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+m}{m}x^n \tag{2} $$
hence by using $(1)$ once and $(2)$ twice we have:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k(n-k) = [x^n]\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^4}=[x^{n-2}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}=\binom{(n-2)+3}{3}=\binom{n+1}{3}\tag{3} $$
as was to be shown.